# Extract user information from the build

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins ver. 2.73.3

I have a sample build task that is triggered by a commit to a Github repository. This is how the build information looks:

[image]

We need to write this username to a separate file and store it in a particular location. How can I achieve it?

**********Edit-1**********
Added a build step that executes a shell command to write the variable GIT_COMMITTER_NAME to a file. This fails(empty file) but if I write, say JENKINS_URL, it is written to the file:

[image]

Comment: Some more info required - what OS / file system are you using? What type of job is this - is this a pipeline job? have you looked at groovy scripting, or plugins to add a build step to allow bash/batch (OS dependent) scripting? What have you tried?

Comment: 1. Jenkins is running on RHEL7
2. This is a 'free-style'(NOT pipeline) job

The information about the (Github)user that triggered the build is already reflected in the build info., I was wondering if there is a way to just extract it. Is a plugin required for this?

Comment: if you add an Execute Shell build step  can you access the environment variable GIT_AUTHOR_NAME ? i.e. `echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` - Does this give you the value you are after?

Comment: Can you check the 'Edit-1' to the original question? I guess these variables are not set by the plug-in, thus, the resultant file is blank. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got a rig to test this on anymore - I was doing stuff like this last year, and have since moved on to pipelines. I also used to use [envinject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-Someusecases) to do stuff with SCM variables after checkout, which may work for you. Good luck, I hope someone else can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the github plugin doesn't set, by default, the variables like GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL etc.
Taking a cue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352950/1106134) answer, I proceeded with using the **placeholders** of the '[pretty option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats)' of [git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) command. I added the following command in the 'Execute Shell' build step of Jenkins job:

```
git show -s --pretty='GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='%aN%n'GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='%aE%n'GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='%cN%n'GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='%cE >> github.properties
```

The output:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=LastName FirstName
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=FirstName.LastName@company.com
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=GitHub Enterprise
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=noreply@github.company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo $variable` name execute `env` in shell, it will give you all environment variables at the time of execution and then you can pick the correct variable. (From Gitlab to Jenkins its `$gitlabUserName`)

Comment: You mean something like 
env
echo "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=\"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME\"" > github.properties

Getting empty name

Comment: no, in your execute shell box just keep `env` and push the code in Git, when Job will get triggered, go to the console and see what all variables are available.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, I see several env. variables in the console output but the ones needed e.g: GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL etc. are missing(I guess the plugin is not setting them, at all)