# Jenkins save author of commit and listen for pushes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I want to ask if there is possible to jenkins pipeline run every time when there is push into some repository in git. and save the author of commit into variable. My code:

```
stage('checkout') {
  steps {
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy-zzzzzzzzzz', url: 'git@website:group/project.git']]])
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your 1st question:  "is possible to Jenkins pipeline run every time when there is push into some repository in git"

answer:  Yes there are various way.

1. To make use of Webhooks. Many SCM provider like Github , BitBucket has this option
2. you can make use of Jenkins git plugins to do that. (refer my screen shot)
   [image]

For your 2nd question: "Save the author of commit into a variable. "
answer: It seems to duplicate question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311341/jenkins-and-git-how-to-grab-a-committers-name/28352950)